# How do I check for the same words in two different lists?

Tags: python, words

How can I check for the same words in two different lists if the words have different lower and uppercase letters?
I wrote this:

```
current_users=["michael", "peta", "jennifer", "clark", "tony"]
new_users=["jeffry", "PETA", "shuff", "TOny", "guy"]

for new_user in new_users:

    if new_user.lower() in current_users:
        print("Sorry, the name "+new_user+" is already taken.")
    else:
        print("The name "+ new_user+ " is available.")
```

But it only works if the first list is in lowercase. Can this code be easily modified to disregard differences in case?

Comment: Not really, just make sure that all the items in that list *are* lowercase when you build it. Or use a `set`, which has faster lookups: `current_users = set(map(str.lower, current_users))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  [`list comprehensions`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

**Example**

```
 if new_user.lower() in [user.lower() for user in current_users]:
```

Comment: A set comprehension will do better if the number of names in the list is quite large

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about that but wasn't sure if I can do it in the If statement.

Comment: I agree @MosesKoledoye but I though this was the cleanest example for a beginner

Answer (score 1):

```
if any(new_user.lower() == user.lower() for user in current_users)
```